# Do I really need to request runtime permissions?

Tags: android

Runtime permissions are essential to ensure that your apps get the required permissions to function, on android 6+ devices, however, it seems like some top developers (gameloft, ea games) do not find the need to implement runtime permissions, and they are rather happy on target SDK 22. So my questions are:

1. Why do I need take the pain of adding run-time permissions, when I can be stay on api 22. This would also save some lines of code.
2. Is it possible to upgrade from target SDK 22 to target SDK 23 once the app has been published? If I plan to stay on SDK 22 for now. It seems like downgrading is not possible. " **Keep in mind that once you publish an APK targeting API level 23 or higher, you won't be able to submit an update targeting API level 22 or lower on any channel.** "

Comment: Keeping up with an old version only serves to postpone work but sooner or later you will have to do it. I have done it and it is not that hard.

Answer (score 3):

> Why do I need take the pain of adding run-time permissions, when I can be stay on api 22

Your "I can be stay on api 22" assumption may not hold up well over time. For example, the user will be told that your app is not compatible with multi-window.

Also, users see that the app is not supporting runtime permissions right away at install time, as they are prompted with the classic install-time permission dialog. Users, over time, will start to think that apps that show that dialog are out of date and not being maintained, and so they may not bother installing your app.

Also, certain third-party libraries that you may want to use may insist upon a higher `targetSdkVersion`.

So, while technically you can have any `targetSdkVersion` you want, there are costs.

> This would also save some lines of code.

Not necessarily. The user can still revoke these permissions from within Settings, and so you may need more error-handling code than before.

> Is it possible to upgrade from target SDK 22 to target SDK 23 once the app has been published?

In general, yes.